Bound of entries of inverse of a unimodular matrix whose row sum is bounded
Many questions have been asked about the bound of the entries of the inverse of a matrix subject to certain conditions. Here my condition is slightly different: let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $n \times n$ unimodular matrix such that
$$\sum_{1 \leq j \leq n}|a_{ij}| \leq M,\,\,\, \text{for all}\,\,\, i,$$
where $M$ is some positive constant. How big can the absolute value of the entries of $A^{-1}$ be?
Naturally, the results to related questions all depend on $n$, and one can easily show that no entries can be greater than $(n-1)!M^{n-1}$. But this bound is terrible, and will never occur in this case. If I were to manufacture a guess, albeit a wild one, I believe a possible upper bound would be $(n-1)!M$. Note that $(n-1)!$ grows faster than $2^n$ and so most answers related to $01$ matrices would fall within my guess, though I cannot find a way to attack this problem.
Any approach or related references would be appreciated.
EDIT. Ok I guess it cannot be that small, just found out that the matrix given by $a_{ij}=1$ for $i=j$ and $a_{ij} = M-1$ for $j=i+1$ and zero elsewhere has inverse with an entry of largest absolute value $(M-1)^{n-1}$. I'll just leave the problem here anyhow.
